# how to deploy unified cloudwatch agent rpm in your alpine based image

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

I have `alpine` based image, where I would like to install `unified cloudwatch agent` from the lists mentioned in this  [DownloadLinks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html). And I choose `https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm` as my package. Inside my docker file I have used like this to call and install the package:

```
RUN  curl -sS -o /tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm && \
     apk add --no-cache  /tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
```

Now the above line downloads the rpm in tmp but as soon as it tried to run apk, it throws me the below error.

```
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  /tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm (missing):
    required by:
                 world[/tmp/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm]
```

So, what is the best way to install rpm in alpine or should I choose a different rmp?